# Loading file into array then sorting from highest to lowest

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file

I am trying to order the largest scores in a file that is loaded into an array. Currently, the program opens the file, then reads it and then splits up each line into two parts - a name and a score; then stores that in an array. I am not sure how I can sort the array to find the largest 10 scores and put that into a listbox. At the moment, the program finds any scores above 0 and puts it in the listbox

```
    Dim FileNum As Integer = FreeFile()

    FileOpen(FileNum, "GameResultsFile", OpenMode.Input)

    For index = 0 To 99
        Dim temp() As String = LineInput(FileNum).Split(",") 'CUTTING LINE INTO TWO SECTIONS


        MemoryGame.HighScores(index).Name = temp(0) 'NAME (First Part of Line)
        MemoryGame.HighScores(index).Score = temp(1) 'SCORE (Second Part of Line)

        If temp(1) > 0 Then 'If any of the scores is above 0 then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(temp(0) + " " + temp(1)) ' display the name of the person who got that score and their score
        End If




    Next
    FileClose()
```

Comment: First things first, get rid of that old VB6 style of I/O. You should be using types from the `System.IO` namespace. Start with the `StreamReader` class for reading text files. You should define a type to represent a player score with a `String` property for name and an `Integer` property for score. As you read the file by line, create an instance of that type and add it to a collection, i.e. a `List(Of T)` where `T` is your type.  You can then call `Sort` on that collection to sort by score and then `Take` to get the first 10 items. Call `ToArray` and then bind to the `ListBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments and explainations in line

```
'Note Imports System.IO
    Structure Player
        Public Score As Integer
        Public Name As String
        'Added a constructor to the structure to make it easy to add new Player
        Public Sub New(myScore As Integer, myName As String)
            Score = myScore
            Name = myName
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Private HighScores(99) As Player

    Private index As Integer 'used in both LoadArray and SortAndDisplayArray

    Private Sub LoadArray()
        Using sr As New StreamReader("GameResultsFile.txt")
            Dim line As String
            Do While sr.Peek() > -1 'Peek checks if there is another character in the file
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                Dim temp() As String = line.Split(","c) 'CUTTING LINE INTO TWO SECTIONS
                'Notice the elements of the temp array are switched to match the
                'Player constructor (Sub New)
                HighScores(index) = New Player(CInt(temp(1)), temp(0))
                index += 1 'not only keeps track of the index but remembers how many elements
                'we have added to HighScores
            Loop
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub SortAndDisplayArray()
        'This is the LINQ way to do it, you can do a great deal in one line of code
        'There is a loop underneath but you don't have to write it.
        'I added a Take clause so we will not get a bunch of 0- in the list box going up to index 99
        ' You might want to show, for example only the top ten scorers, so change to Take 10
        Dim orderArray = From scorer In HighScores Order By scorer.Score Descending Select $"{scorer.Score} - {scorer.Name}" Take index
        ListBox1.DataSource = orderArray.ToList
    End Sub
```

I still think a List(Of T) would be easier but I have a feeling your assignment requires you to use an array.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing is how to display the leaderboard with the name first and then the score?

Comment: In the Select portion of the Linq change `$"{scorer.Score} - {scorer.Name}"` to `$"{scorer.Name} - {scorer.Score}"`  The $ tells the compiler to substitute the variable is the curly brackets. The spaces and the hyphen are literal. You could change the hyphen to a comma or anything you want or just leave spaces.

Comment: One last thing, where you have 'I added a Take clause so we will not get a bunch of 0- in the list box going up to index 99' that does not work as the listbox is still filled up with 0s

Comment: You do have `Private index As Integer` at the Form level not in a Sub, right? The Take index is at the very end of the Linq, yes? It works for me with may sample file. Can you open your file in Notepad and check for anything beyond your last entry. I mean maybe a return or tab that you can't see.

Comment: pastebin.com/Rr43EwwR - I am sure it is all correct but, it still is loading the zeros

Comment: I do see a difference. My file has a .txt extension. This is a text file, yes? Give it a .txt and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: My file is saved without the .txt. It doesn't load with .txt

Comment: Can you open it in notepad?

Comment: Yes, you can open it in NotePad. The "GamesResultFile" is saved as a "File"

Comment: Change the name of the file to GameResultsFile.txt and change your code in the Stream Reader to the same.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you may have extensions turned off in File Explorer. You might already have a .txt extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it something like this using [IComparable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321292/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-the-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-basi)

First I would load the data from your text file like so and save the data to a [List Of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and the Type would be the `Player` class down below.

```
    '' Get Data From Text File And Create An Anonymous Type
    Private Sub LoadPlayerAndScore(path As String)

    '' Load data from text file
    Dim data = From line In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
               Let val = line.Split(",")
               Select New With {Key .Name = val(0), Key .Score = val(1)}

    '' Save data to list
    For Each pair In data
        Dim player As New Player With {
            .Name = pair.Name,
            .Score = pair.Score
        }
        playersList.Add(player)
    Next

End Sub
```

I would then go on to create a player class which will Implement the ICompareble listed above.

```
Class Player
Implements IComparable(Of Player)
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Score As Integer

Public Sub Player(ByVal name As String, ByVal score As Integer)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Score = score
End Sub

'' Sort Player From The Hightest Score To The Lowest Score
Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(other As Player) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Player).CompareTo
    Return other.Score.CompareTo(Me.Score)
End Function
End Class
```

I would then create some public variables such as

```
Dim playersList As New List(Of Player)
Dim fileLocation As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Settings.txt")
```

Change the path to your file's location.
And finally in a [Form Load Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx)
 I would call it all like this

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '' Load Data From Text File On Desktop
    LoadPlayerAndScore(path:=fileLocation)

    '' Sort List
    playersList.Sort()

    '' Add Values To List
    For Each p As Player In playersList
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Name: " + p.Name + " Score: " + p.Score.ToString())
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is what the code should look something like altogether

```
Public Class Form1
Dim playersList As New List(Of Player)
Dim fileLocation As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Settings.txt")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '' Load Data From Text File On Desktop
    LoadPlayerAndScore(path:=fileLocation)

    '' Sort List
    playersList.Sort()

    '' Add Values To List
    For Each p As Player In playersList
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Name: " + p.Name + " Score: " + p.Score.ToString())
    Next

End Sub
'' Get Data From Text File And Create An Anonymous Type
Private Sub LoadPlayerAndScore(path As String)

    '' Load data from text file
    Dim data = From line In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
               Let val = line.Split(",")
               Select New With {Key .Name = val(0), Key .Score = val(1)}

    '' Save data to list
    For Each pair In data
        Dim player As New Player With {
            .Name = pair.Name,
            .Score = pair.Score
        }
        playersList.Add(player)
    Next

End Sub
End Class

Class Player
Implements IComparable(Of Player)
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Score As Integer

Public Sub Player(ByVal name As String, ByVal score As Integer)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Score = score
End Sub
'' Sort Player From The Hightest Score To The Lowest Score
Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(other As Player) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Player).CompareTo
    Return other.Score.CompareTo(Me.Score)
End Function
End Class
```

Here is the output I got
[image: Results]
And here is what the text files data looked like.
`ANDREW,25`
`MERVE,12`
`RUZGAR,50`
And for the top ten people, follow the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

How about try this?

```
Dim sortedArray = _
    File _
        .ReadAllLines("GameResultsFile") _
        .Select(Function (line) line.Split(","c)) _
        .Select(Function (parts) New With { .Name = parts(0), .Score = Integer.Parse(parts(1)) }) _
        .OrderByDescending(Function (x) x.Score) _
        .Select(Function (x) x.Name & " " & x.Score)
        .ToArray()

For Each item As String In sortedArray
    ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
Next
```